# Rounding Up or Down in Velocity

Tags: java, rounding, velocity

Simple question: Can I do the equivalent of Math.ceil and Math.floor in a Velocity template?  From what I could find I would have to use [MathTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/MathTool.html), but that doesn't seem to have what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you could work with `MathTool.roundToInt()` and adding/subtracting 1, but it should also be possible to provide an object with your methods that might provide what you need.

Also have a look at  [Velocity Tools 2.0](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/) whose [MathTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/MathTool.html) has methods floor() and ceil().

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the Tools 2.0 MathTool for greatest type flexibility, but Velocity Engine's 1.6+ support static methods by putting the class itself into the context.  So the quick and easy solution is:

context.put("Math", Math.class);

$Math.ceil($foo)
$Math.floor($bar)